# when I go to scrapy to convert my web scraping data to csv! No matter how many rows I have. In just one row, the data of all rows is being inserted

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazondawinItem

class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'
    pagenumber = 3
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&i=computers&crid=27GFGJVF4KNRP&sprefix=%2Ccomputers%2C725&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_1_0_recent'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazondawinItem()
        name = response.css('.a-size-medium::text').extract()
        try:
            old_price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-micro .a-text-price span::text').extract()
        except:
            old_price = None
        price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-micro .a-price-whole::text').extract()
        try:
            review = response.css('.s-link-style .s-underline-text::text').extract()
        except:
            review = None


        imagelink = response.css('.s-image::attr(src)').extract()

        items['name'] = name
        items['old_price'] = old_price
        items['price'] = price
        items['review'] = review
        items['imagelink'] = imagelink
        # description =
        # ram =
        # brand =
        # cpu_model =
        yield items
```

Here when I go to scrapy to convert my web scraping data to csv file or any file! No matter how many rows I have. In just one row, the data of all rows is being inserted. or import. Suppose, I have 200 rows in 1 column. But I am getting 200 rows of data in one row.

Comment: Are you sure `yield` is correct here?  I would have expected `return`, not `yield`.

Comment: What is `AmazondawinItem()`? Please [edit] your question and post the code where it is defined, including the code used to write your CSV.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're yielding all the items instead of yielding each item separately.

**A not so nice solution:**

```py
import scrapy
# from ..items import AmazondawinItem


class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'
    pagenumber = 3
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&i=computers&crid=27GFGJVF4KNRP&sprefix=%2Ccomputers%2C725&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_1_0_recent'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # items = AmazondawinItem()

        name = response.css('.a-size-medium::text').extract()
        try:
            old_price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-micro .a-text-price span::text').extract()
        except:
            old_price = None
        price = response.css('.a-spacing-top-micro .a-price-whole::text').extract()
        try:
            review = response.css('.s-link-style .s-underline-text::text').extract()
        except:
            review = None

        imagelink = response.css('.s-image::attr(src)').extract()
        # items = dict()
        # items['name'] = name
        # items['old_price'] = old_price
        # items['price'] = price
        # items['review'] = review
        # items['imagelink'] = imagelink

        items = dict()
        for (items['name'], items['old_price'], items['price'], items['review'], items['imagelink']) in zip(name, old_price, price, review, imagelink):
            yield items
        # description =
        # ram =
        # brand =
        # cpu_model =
        # yield items
```

**A better solution:**

1. Remove the `try except`, `get()` function will return none if no value was found. It's better not to use it in spiders anyway.
2. Get the items one by one.
3. Just replace the dict part with your item, just make sure it's inside the loop.

```py
import scrapy
# from ..items import AmazondawinItem


class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazon'
    pagenumber = 3
    allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop&i=computers&crid=27GFGJVF4KNRP&sprefix=%2Ccomputers%2C725&ref=nb_sb_ss_recent_1_0_recent'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for row in response.css('div.s-result-list div.s-result-item.s-asin'):
            # items = AmazondawinItem()
            items = dict()
            items['name'] = row.css('.a-size-medium::text').get()
            items['old_price'] = row.css('.a-spacing-top-micro .a-text-price span::text').get()
            items['price'] = response.css('.a-spacing-top-micro .a-price-whole::text').get()
            items['review'] = row.css('.s-link-style .s-underline-text::text').get()
            items['imagelink'] = row.css('.s-image::attr(src)').get()
            yield items
        # description =
        # ram =
        # brand =
        # cpu_model =
        # yield items
```